# Using grep or sed in a foreach loop won't work

Tags: variables, foreach, sed, grep, csh

I've spent countless hours trying to get this work and I think it's time to get some help.  I have a 2-column file - let's call it "result.txt" with a list of values like this:

```
fileA.ext  -10.3 
fileB.ext  -9.8
fileC_1.ext  -9.7
fileC_2.ext -9.5
fileD.ext  -9.4
fileC_3.ext -9.3
```

I want to recreate this list using only unique results for each file type, so it should look like this:

```
fileA.ext  -10.3 
fileB.ext  -9.8
fileC_1.ext  -9.7
fileD.ext  -9.4
```

I created a list of files which would be able to do this by using grep or sed to extract the first line containing the matching file:

```
fileA
fileB
fileC
fileD
```

We'll call this `result2.txt`.

I have attempted to write the following c-shell script:

```
foreach l (`cat result2.txt`)
    set name = "$l"
    echo "$name"
    grep -m1 "$name" result.txt >> result3.txt
end
```

The output file, "result3.txt" is empty.  The script runs perfectly up to the grep command.  When I run the grep command outside of the loop, using a line from result2.txt, it works fine.  I get the same result using this: `sed -n '/"\$name\"/p'`
And I think I tried an awk command at some point.
The problem seems to be in getting those programs to recognise the `$name` or `$l` variables.  I have tried different combinations of " and ' around `$name` and I have tried adding backslashes: e.g. `$\name`.  Can anyone please tell me what the issue is?
Thanks

Comment: sorry but not clear what you really want. From first file, what do you expect in final (give maybe a sample of the wanted result)

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply.  The result I wanted is in the second list 2-column list I provided.  I have now figured out the cause of the problem (see comments below other answers).  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for awk. Use underscore or whitespace as the field separator, and print a line only if the first field has not been seen yet:

```
awk -F '[_[:space:]]+' '!seen[$1]++' << END
fileA.ext -10.3
fileB.ext -9.8
fileC_1.ext -9.7
fileC_2.ext -9.5
fileD.ext -9.4
fileC_3.ext -9.3
END
```

```
fileA.ext -10.3
fileB.ext -9.8
fileC_1.ext -9.7
fileD.ext -9.4
```

Comment: +1: I was going to write `-F' *|_'` but you already posted it while I was editing the question `:)`. Have a question, is there a benefit of using `[:space:]` as delimiter? Portability?

Comment: It includes both spaces and tabs. It's the POSIX regex equivalent of Perl's `\s`

Comment: Thanks, won't this `-F' *'` cover it too? Since `*` will say look for 0 or more spaces. Sorry not challenging your answer just wanted to gather some insight.

Comment: What if the file contains tabs instead of spaces?

Comment: Hmm, got it. Thanks so much @glennjackman. I was missing that fact that `[:space:]` will consider `^I` like you said. Kept on thinking `tabs` as more `spaces`. Thanks again!

Comment: @glenn jackman, thanks for the answer.  I'm sure that will come in handy.  I finally figured out the reason why my original script, your answer and the answers below wouldn't work.  I had used a windows program to prepare 'result2.txt' from 'result1.txt', so the file was saved in DOS format.  grep, sed and awk can't seem to deal with the \r\n line endings in these files.  As soon as I ran dos2unix on 'result2.txt' my script started working!  Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried in CSH and both your version and the following simplified version just work. Note, no quotation marks at all.

```
foreach name (`cat result2.txt`)
    grep -m1 $name result.txt >>result3.txt
end
```

Could you please check whether `result.txt` really contains what you mentioned at the beginning?

```
cat result.txt
```

Comment: thanks for verifying that the script worked.  Thanks to you, I figured out what the problem was. I had used a windows program to prepare 'result2.txt' from 'result1.txt', so the file was saved in DOS format. grep, sed and awk can't seem to deal with the \r\n line endings in these files. As soon as I ran dos2unix on 'result2.txt' my script started working! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It's always good to keep in mind such stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n 's/.*/²&³/;H
$ {x;s/\(.\).*/&\1/
t again
: again
   s/²\([^_]\{1,\}_\)\(.*\)\²\1[^³]*³./²\1\2/
   t again
   s/.\(.*\)./\1/;s/[²³]//g
   p
   }' YourFile
```

Use of 2 temporary delimiter `²` and `³` due to limitation in \n manipulation

Comment: thanks for the input.  finally figured out the reason why my original script, your answer and the answers below wouldn't work. I had used a windows program to prepare 'result2.txt' from 'result1.txt', so the file was saved in DOS format. grep, sed and awk can't seem to deal with the \r\n line endings in these files. As soon as I ran dos2unix on 'result2.txt' my script started working! I tried your script, but I kept getting the message <unmatched 's>.  Maybe I missed something.  Anyway, thanks again for your help.

Comment: wich version of sed are you using on windows ? I suspect a `\` too much or missing under windows sed/shell

Comment: I used sed on Red Hat Enterprise Linux.  I just used Microsoft Excel on windows to remove duplicates (I now know that uniq -u would have been fine).

Comment: try removing `\`before the `{` and `}` that react differently depending of sed version